# Button's label become editable on clicking it

Tags: css, angularjs, html

My button's label becomes editable upon clicking on it. I get a text cursor and I'm able to edit it. I want to prevent this.

[image]

Becomes editable.

[image]

Here is the CSS for the button:

```
.class{
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-position-y: 3px;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 111;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is my HTML code for it:

```
<input class="smnextlevelbtn"
       type="button"
       value="{{nextlevellabel}}"
       ng-click="nextLevel()" />
```

Comment: can you make a live demo/fiddle for this ?

Comment: Probably what is editable, is a transparent input field that sits on top of the thing that looks like a button

Comment: @ user2486 : Not able to replicate outside of my application.

Comment: @ aletzo Button label 'Next Level' becomes on clicking on it. Before event fires, in fraction of second i can able to see the text cursor.

Comment: If you are using <input> tag then write readonly="readonly" inside the tag or kindly provide the HTML.

Comment: Can you please also provide the html and if possible any js involved?

Comment: This is **not** the default behavior of the browser, meaning that you have either used a `contenteditable` attribute on the element, or a JS loaded on your page is causing the element to be editable. Please share the generated markup and reproduce your example in an MCVE.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue. I have changed <input> tag to <button> like this <button class="smnextlevelbtn" ng-click="nextLevel()">{{nextlevellabel}} </button>